Error report in using Rust crate calamine
I wrote a piece of Rust code that uses crate calamine, which looks like this
use calamine::{open_workbook, Range, Reader, Xlsx, DataType};
use std::error::Error;
 
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Record {
    wavelength: f64,
    global_tilt: f64,
}
 
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let path = format!("{}/data/am15.xlsx", std::env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR"));
    let mut workbook: Xlsx<_> = open_workbook(&path)?;
 
    if let Some(Ok(range)) = workbook.worksheet_range("Sheet1").ok() {
        let mut rows_read = 0;
 
        // Iterate over the rows in the range
        for row in range.rows() {
            if rows_read >= 10 {
                break;
            }
 
            // Parse the row into a Record struct
            let record = Record {
                wavelength: row.get(0).and_then(|cell| cell.get_float()).unwrap_or(0.0),
                global_tilt: row.get(1).and_then(|cell| cell.get_float()).unwrap_or(0.0),
            };
 
            // Print the record
            println!("Wavelength: {}, Global tilt: {}", record.wavelength, record.global_tilt);
            rows_read += 1;
        }
    } else {
        println!("Worksheet 'Sheet1' not found or could not be read.");
    }
 
    Ok(())
} 

But the compilation always reports the following error:
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/print_header.rs:14:15
   |
14 |     if let Ok(Ok(range)) = workbook.worksheet_range("Sheet1") {
   |               ^^^^^^^^^    ---------------------------------- this expression has type `Result<calamine::Range<Data>, XlsxError>`
   |               |
   |               expected `Range<Data>`, found `Result<_, _>`
   |
   = note: expected struct `calamine::Range<Data>`
                found enum `Result<_, _>`

The error message I provided seems to be from a Rust compiler (rustc) indicating a type mismatch issue in my code. It looks like I am trying to match against a nested Result type instead of the expected Range type. So how can I fix this error?

Your snippet does not match the error message. Anyway, have you tried removing the inner Ok

The code and error do not match

Remove the Some from the if let. worksheet_range returns Result<_, _> not Result<Result<_, _>>.
The updated code should be:
use calamine::{open_workbook, Range, Reader, Xlsx, DataType};
use std::error::Error;
 
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Record {
    wavelength: f64,
    global_tilt: f64,
}
 
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let path = format!("{}/data/am15.xlsx", std::env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR"));
    let mut workbook: Xlsx<_> = open_workbook(&path)?;
 
    if let Ok(range) = workbook.worksheet_range("Sheet1") {
        let mut rows_read = 0;
 
        // Iterate over the rows in the range
        for row in range.rows() {
            if rows_read >= 10 {
                break;
            }
 
            // Parse the row into a Record struct
            let record = Record {
                wavelength: row.get(0).and_then(|cell| cell.get_float()).unwrap_or(0.0),
                global_tilt: row.get(1).and_then(|cell| cell.get_float()).unwrap_or(0.0),
            };
 
            // Print the record
            println!("Wavelength: {}, Global tilt: {}", record.wavelength, record.global_tilt);
            rows_read += 1;
        }
    } else {
        println!("Worksheet 'Sheet1' not found or could not be read.");
    }
 
    Ok(())
}

As a sugegstion, since you are returning Result from the main, instead of using if let, simply use ?, like:
use calamine::{open_workbook, DataType, Range, Reader, Xlsx};
use std::error::Error;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Record {
    wavelength: f64,
    global_tilt: f64,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let path = format!("{}/data/am15.xlsx", std::env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR"));
    let mut workbook: Xlsx<_> = open_workbook(&path)?;

    let range = workbook.worksheet_range("Sheet1")?;
    let mut rows_read = 0;

    // Iterate over the rows in the range
    for row in range.rows() {
        if rows_read >= 10 {
            break;
        }

        // Parse the row into a Record struct
        let record = Record {
            wavelength: row.get(0).and_then(|cell| cell.get_float()).unwrap_or(0.0),
            global_tilt: row.get(1).and_then(|cell| cell.get_float()).unwrap_or(0.0),
        };

        // Print the record
        println!(
            "Wavelength: {}, Global tilt: {}",
            record.wavelength, record.global_tilt
        );
        rows_read += 1;
    }

    Ok(())
}


Yes, it works now, thanks very much！
